# Read an object from compressed file generated from ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, python

I have made a simple game Map Editor and I want to save a array that contain map tile info to a file, as below:

```
var arr:Array = [.....2d tile info in it...];
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeObject(arr);
ba.compress();
var file:File = new File();
file.save(ba);
```

I had successfully saved a compressed object to a file.
Now the problem is my server side need to read this file and decompress the array out from the file, then convert it to a Python list.  Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you use ByteArray? Just save xml or json file.

Comment: I just want to let the config file more little, and easily ,fast for python to read the data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual almost any `Is that possible?` question is answered **Yes**. To do that, you need to know compression method used by ActionScript (most possibly is some of zlib methods). After that you need to somehow get serialization format of array, and read it back.

But zipped Json and XML can be not much larger than binary compressed.

Also this question has not much to do with game programming, so you can try it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).